# Publishing a .NET 6 with React JS application on IIS Manager giving 404 error when accessing APIs

Tags: reactjs, .net, iis, hosting, .net-6.0

I created a .NET 6 Project with React JS with the Visual Studio template. I am trying to host it on IIS Manager on `localhost:82`.
I've created a folder inside of `inetpub\wwwroot\PublishFiles` to store my published files.
But the issue is the publish file genereated has a wwwroot folder inside of it.
`wwwroot\PublishFiles\wwwroot`

When I point my IIS website physical location to `wwwroot\PublishFiles\wwwroot` it is displaying the website but I cannot access any controllers from the server side. It is giving me a 404 error when I'm trying to access this API
`http://localhost:82/Controller/APIName`

I have already installed the .NET 6 hosting files that are required.

I have added this to my `Progam.cs` but it hasn't worked

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); 
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: Not sure which tutorial you are following, but the right folder to use for your IIS site is simply `wwwroot\PublishFiles`.

Comment: I’ve already tried that, but since the newest .NET 6 and ReactJS publish files have a wwwroot inside them, `wwwroot\PublishFiles\wwwroot` where the index page is present, IIS does not seem to load the index page. If I only give `wwwroot\PublishFiles` I get a blank page.

Comment: You got a blank page for some other cause, but the IIS site must point to the folder I said, because that’s how ASP.NET Core/React SPA template works. Unless people have access to your machine and source code, I don’t think the blank page issue can be fully investigated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out why my IIS could not load my Index page. So the .NET6 Hosting package that was installed on my system was `v6.0.5`. On installing the newest bundle `v6.0.19` and pointing IIS to the `wwwroot\PublishFiles` folder it started to work correctly.